# Prove that $ ∇⋅(a\vec A )=a(∇⋅\vec A )+(\vec A ⋅∇)a$

Tags: calculus, vectors, proof-explanation

$\vec{A}$ is a vector field and each of its component is a function of x, y, and z:

$\vec{A} = u\hat{i} + v\hat{i} + w\hat{k}$

$u = u(x,y,z)$

$v = v(x,y,z)$

$w = w(x,y,z)$

a is a scalar function of x, y, and z.

---

**$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = a(\nabla\cdot\vec{A}) + (\vec{A}\cdot\nabla)a$**

$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = \frac{\partial (au)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (av)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial (aw)}{\partial z}$

$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = \dots$

I have no idea how to continue.

Many thanks for the help.

**Solution:**

$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = \frac{\partial a}{\partial x}u + a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial a}{\partial y}v + a\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial a}{\partial x}w + a\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$

$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = (a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + a\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + a\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}) + (\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}u + \frac{\partial a}{\partial y}v + \frac{\partial a}{\partial z}w)$

$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = a(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}) + (\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}v + \frac{\partial }{\partial z}w)a$

**$\nabla\cdot(a\vec{A}) = a(\nabla\cdot\vec{A}) + (\vec{A}\cdot\nabla)a$**

Comment: Try applying the product rule to each of the partial derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, Is my solution correct?

Comment: It generally looks good, but remember that all the derivatives we're taking here should be partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

using the product rule we have
$$
\frac{\partial (au)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}u+a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial (av)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}u+a\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial (aw)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}u+a\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
$$

Now sum these and reorder ( and factorize $a$) and you have the result.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Is my solution correct?

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure. Is ∇⋅A⃗ same as A⃗ ⋅∇, because of the dot product?

Comment: U's should be replaced with v in 2nd Eq. and w in 3rd Eq.

Comment: Yes. Your solution is correct. (use $\partial$ and not $d$ for partial derivative :)